# Parse ASP.Net JSON Date Format to Lua?

Tags: asp.net, regex, json, lua

I don't know any ASP.NET, and I need a function in Lua that can convert the date.

Example date: `"\/Date(1397304050320)\/"` --> `4/12/2014`

Is the function below translatable to Lua?
If you don't know Lua can you try to translate the matching patterns for me?

I've already found this function:

```c#
function FixJsonDates(data) {
    //microsoft script service perform the following to fix the dates.
    //json date:\/Date(1317307437667-0400)\/"
    //javasccript format required: new Date(1317307437667-0400)

    //copied from micrsoft generated fiel.
   var _dateRegEx = new RegExp('(^|[^\\\\])\\"\\\\/Date\\((-?[0-9]+)(?:[a-zA-Z]|(?:\\+|-)[0-9]{4})?\\)\\\\/\\"', 'g');
   var exp = data.replace(_dateRegEx, "$1new Date($2)");
   return eval(exp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the date from a string and convert to a date, try

```
local s = "some text/Date(1397304050320)/more text"
local t = s:match("/Date%((%d+)%)/")
print(os.date("%D",t/1000))
```

In Lua, `os.date` requires times in seconds. Apparently the number you have is in milliseconds.

Comment: @kikito, if you use `local`, you cannot copy and paste it into an interactive session.

Comment: But he wants to reimplement a function, not to use the code in an interactive session.